# Сохранение пути, сброс выделенного объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пишу приложение (конечный вариант - игра в жанре rts) в юнити, столкнулся с проблемой. Если в двух словах, то выбирал объект при нажатии левой кнопки мыши, при нажатии правой кнопки я обнулял выбранный объект, т.е. так:

```
    private void SelectedObjectTap(){
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) { 
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 10000)) {
            if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
                target = hit.point;
                GameObject rayCastedGO;
                rayCastedGO = hit.collider.gameObject;
                this.SelectedObject = rayCastedGO;
            }
        }
    } else if (Input.GetMouseButton(1)){
        SelectedObject = null;
      }
    }
```

И все в принципе работало, но потом я заметил, что выбранный юнит не запоминает свой путь и при обнулении встает на месте. Я решил отказаться от обнуления выбранного объекта и решил сделать отдельный объект, который засунул под террэйн и при нажатии правой кнопки мыши в выбранный объект отправлял этот отдельный объект.

```
    else if (Input.GetMouseButton(1)){
        this.SelectedObject = Empty;
    }
```

Управление у меня реализовано посредством метода Vector3.MoveTowards (выбранный объект, destination, скорость). При нажатии левой кнопки мыши я запоминаю координаты в destination, а при нажатии правой destination... Вот код:

```
    public void MouseClick(){
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)){
            Ray ray2 = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray2, out hit, 10000)) {
                destination = hit.point;
            } 
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1)){
            destination = new Vector3(0,-30,0);
        }
    }
```

Т.к. у меня всего три юнита на карте, то я сделал следующее:

```
    private void MoveTransfer() {
        if (flag1 == true) { 
            transferArcher.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transferArcher.transform.position, transfer1, speedArcher);
        }
        if (flag2 == true) { 
            transferBarbarian.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transferBarbarian.transform.position, transfer2, speedBarbarian);
        }
        if (flag3 == true) { 
            transferHorseman.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transferHorseman.transform.position, transfer3, speedHorseman);
        }
        if (flagEmpty == true) {
            Empty.transform.position = transferEmpty;
        }
    }
```

Ранее в переменные transfer1-3 и transferEmpty я записывал значение destination, чтобы каждый юнит шел своей дорогой.

Проблема заключается в том, что каждый юнит идет по своему пути, если я щелкаю на юните ЛК, щелкаю на террэйн ЛК - юнит идет, щелкаю на втором юните также, потом нажимаю ПК, и все, юнит останавливается и не идет по своему маршруту.

P.S. Еще один вопрос, подскажите, как можно запомнить пройденный путь юнита.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте создать клас юнит у которого будет переменная дестинейшн ,
в апдейте проверяйте есть ли что-то в переменной, если да то в апдейте передвигать юнита пока не дойдёт до точки назначения.
В классе где обрабатываете мышь выбранному юниту указывайте точку назначения.
В этом же классе можно сохранять в массив пройденный путь с неким интервалом, например каждые 10 единиц пройденного пути.
Сохранять все точки пройденного пути плохая идея их будет очень много, а так с интервалом если надо будет юниту вернуться можно интерпретировать путь по контрольным точкам